# How do I upload images on django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, file-upload

I have been trying to upload an image in Django using a custom view and I'm failing. The admin panel is letting me upload though, what could be the problem? I have installed Pillow and made sure that the form has the multipart/form-data property. Am I supposed to make a separate model for images?

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    username = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    gender = models.TextField(max_length=10)  
    dob = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)  
    phone_no = models.CharField(unique=True, max_length=9)  
    address = models.CharField(max_length=50)  
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="profile_pic/")
    nrc_front = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="nrc_front/")
    nrc_back = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True, upload_to="nrc_back/")
    is_verified = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_group_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_group_member = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    temp_code = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.username)
```

settings.py

```
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(
    BASE_DIR / 'media'
)
```

view.py

```
def updateProfilePic(request):
    profiledata = get_profile_data(request)
    form = UpdateProfilePicForm()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = UpdateProfilePicForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            profile_pic = form.cleaned_data.get("profile_pic")
            Profile.objects.filter(username=request.user).update(profile_pic=profile_pic)
            return redirect('profile')
    else:
        form = UpdateProfilePicForm()
    context = {
        "profiledata":profiledata,
        "form":form
    }
    return render(request, 'base/profile-update-picture.html', context)
```

template

```
{% extends 'base/base.html' %}

{% block title %}Update Picture{% endblock %}

{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <div class="form-container shadow p-3 mb-5 bg-white rounded mx-auto">
        {% crispy form %}
    </div>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

browser rendering

```
<form action="/update-profile-picture/" class="form-group" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

in my url.py

```
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

can you try

```
Profile.objects.filter(username=request.user)
```

to:

```
user_profile = Profile.objects.get(username=request.user)
user_profile.profile_pic = profile_pic
user_profile.save()
```

Comment: It has worked with this change. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You just change this code from view.py

```
Profile.objects.filter(username=request.user).update(profile_pic=profile_pic)
```

To:

Example your table User is this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    name_user=models.CharField(max_lenght=50)
```

Change view.py code to:

```
Profile.objects.filter(username__name_user=request.user).update(profile_pic=profile_pic)
```

Comment: I changed it and it hasn't work

Comment: I'm using the default auth_user table